# AJAX Request every second

Tags: javascript, ajax

More specifically, I would like to wait until the current request is handled. Once it is handled, make an additional one, waiting a second after the previous one has been handled. In the case of a disconnection client-side, I would like the requests to continue being made, so the whole process doesn't just stop.

My code below just makes a bunch of requests at once:

```
       makeLiveRequest(testState) {
            var that = this;

            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: '/getData',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(response) {
                    that.$set(that.state, 'testData', response);
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                    that.convertChartData();
                    setTimeout(that.makeLiveRequest, 5000);
                }
            });

            this.makeLiveChartRequest();
        },
```

Looking online, it seems that setInterval is not recommended. Any ideas?

Comment: In the case of a disconnection client-side, then there is no more client application to make the request. So I think that is impossible.

Comment: Your logic looks fine, though, are you sure `that` has a `makeLiveRequest` method? it wouldn't as a callback to settimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't address the exact reason why subsequent request in initiating (may be its resolving very quickly) 
But the point I can notice here is:
the callback we passed to `setTimeout` runs in the context of `window` object, so your
`that = this` will store `window` to `that` variable and will not get the dependent data, so there can be logical failure of what you want to achieve.

instead do call like

`setTimeout(that.makeLiveRequest.bind(that,<your arg value for testState>), 5000);`

or pass a callback to `setTimeout` and call `that.makeLiveRequest(arg)` from inside of that.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library, mainly the forever method.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200981/node-js-how-to-perform-endless-loop-with-async-module#answer-29201161)